# esticar label horizontalmente num panel em c#

Tags: c#, .net, label

Que propriedades usar para esticar uma label (a label em questão tem o texto "atalhos") em um panel?

Quero que ela ocupe horizontalmente todo o espaço do panel da esquerda.

Exemplo programa: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8036829/image1.png

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) como criar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável. Coloque o seu código na pergunta em vez de colocar um *link* para o código, torna mais fácil ajuda-lo. Convém ainda mencionar se esta a usar *WinForms* ou *WPF* (seria simples de inferir se tivesse colocado o código).

Answer (score 2):

Assumindo que você queira mudar pelo modo *Design* do *Visual Studio*, você pode *settar* a propriedade **AutoSize** do `Label` para `False` e alterar a propriedade **Dock** para `Top`, porém isso fará com que o `Label` fique "colado" também na borda de cima do painel.

Uma alternativa é apenas alterar a propriedade **AutoSize** para `False` e "esticar" o label até ele ficar do tamanho que você precisa.